# Scrapy not working as expected

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my `Scrapy` spider. I'm trying to scrape some data from web. But I don't know how to force `Scrapy` to follow links recursively. Where is my mistake?

```
import re
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from YellowPagesOfMoldova.items import YellowpagesofmoldovaItem
from scrapy.item import Item

class YellowSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'yellow'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.md']
    start_urls = [ 'http://www.yellowpages.md/eng/companies/info/8939-arc-publishing-house']
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('eng.+')), follow=True),
        )

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        i = YellowpagesofmoldovaItem()
        i['url']            = response.url
        i['locality']       = sel.xpath("//tr[3]/td/p[1]/span[1]/text()").extract()
        i['title']          = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        i['title2']         = sel.xpath("//td/h1/text()").extract()
        i['website']        = sel.xpath("//p[2]/a/text()").extract()
        i['activity']       = sel.xpath("//tbody/tr[4]/td/p/text()").extract()
        i['street']         = sel.xpath("//tr/td/p[1]/span[2]/text()").extract()
        return i
```

Thanks.

I resolved this trouble. Now it works perfectly. It looks so:

```
import re
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from YellowPagesOfMoldova.items import YellowpagesofmoldovaItem
from scrapy.item import Item

class YellowSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'yellow'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.md']
    start_urls = [ 'http://www.yellowpages.md/eng/companies/info/8939-arc-publishing-house']
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('eng.+')),callback='parse_items', follow=True),

        )

    def parse_items(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        i = YellowpagesofmoldovaItem()
        i['url']            = response.url
        i['locality']       = sel.xpath("//tr[3]/td/p[1]/span[1]/text()").extract()
        i['title']          = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        i['title2']         = sel.xpath("//td/h1/text()").extract()
        i['website']        = sel.xpath("//p[2]/a/text()").extract()
        i['activity']       = sel.xpath("//tbody/tr[4]/td/p/text()").extract()
        i['street']         = sel.xpath("//tr/td/p[1]/span[2]/text()").extract()
        return i
```

Comment: Oh, was posting my answer while you were editing. Cool that you got it figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CrawlSpider's `parse` method should not be overridden because that's where all the "magic" happens. (See the [warning about `parse` here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)).

Change `def parse` to `def parse_page` and reference this callback in your Rule: `Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('eng.+')), callback='parse_page', follow=True),`